# Can NDK include a .lib file?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use a C++ library (prebuilt 3rd party) that is distributed as a .lib library object file?  Can this be done.  I see provisions for including .a files, but what i've got is a .lib file.

Answer (score 0):

If it is build for ARM you can include it, if not you are out of luck. A .lib file is usually for Windows, so probably the latter. You need to either get the source or get them to build it  with the NDK and send you the object file.